# ROS 2 Communication Issue between Windows and WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros2, windows, ros-foxy

I am currently facing an issue with ROS 2 communication between a Windows environment running ROS 2 Foxy and a WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 environment running ROS 2 Iron. This setup used to work seamlessly a few weeks ago, but recently, I encountered difficulties. It's worth mentioning that I have attempted to update ROS 2 on both sides, which raises the question of whether this could be related to the issue.

Here's the current setup:

- ROS 2 Foxy on Windows 11.
- ROS 2 Iron on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.
- Both environments are configured with `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` set to 1.

When I run basic ROS 2 examples on each operating system separately, everything works as expected. However, when I attempt to establish communication between the two, it fails. Additionally, I've noticed that I am unable to use ROS 2 multicast functionality, even though I can use it within each respective OS.

It appears that when I initiate a ROS 2 script on WSL2, Windows seems to terminate or block it. In some instances, I've managed to receive a message just before the script was halted. This leads me to believe that the connection is established, but Windows may be interfering.

I've already ruled out the firewall as the source of the problem by testing with it disabled. However, I'm uncertain about the next steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or have suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! After updating Windows OS, firewall settings are changed sometimes. Therefore, can you please confirm that both machines can ping each other? If so, please publish a message from one machine and echo it on another machine. For example, machine 1: `ros2 topic pub -r 1 /my_msg std_msgs/msg/String data:\ 'Hello ROS'` and machine 2: `ros2 topic echo /my_msg` . You may refer to [this blog post](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-multiple-machines-including-raspberry-pi/).